# shell script to parse Swift file to extract all methods in them

Tags: swift, bash, shell, sed

I have a swift file that I need to read and find out all methods in it. Is there a way I can do so using shell script (or any command line script)

I have tried `swiftc -dum-ast` which dumps the AST of the swift file. I'm working over it, but I do not have correct answer till now.

Comment: `grep func MySwiftFile.swift`

Comment: will it always work? what if func keyword is present in comment?

Comment: or there is a word like "function" - that is inclusive of func.

Comment: It will print out all lines with `func` in them including comments and words such as `dysfunctional`.

Comment: How can we fix this? I'm sorry - a little poor in shell script :-(

Comment: Why negative votes guys? Please let me know if I need an improvement.

Comment: `grep 'func ' MySwiftFile.swift` will look for `func` with a space after it.  Eliminating comments is more work.

Comment: `swiftc MySwiftFile.swift -print-ast | grep ' func ' > result.txt`

Comment: This works, please write an answer for this and I'll accept it as correct one.

Comment: @prabodhprakash the negative votes are presumably because you didn't provide a [mcve] per the minimal requirements for writing a question, see [ask].

Comment: I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-print-ast` option of the *swiftc* compiler to parse the file and dump the functions and variables.  Combine that with `grep` to find just the functions and redirect that to a result file:

```
swiftc MySwiftFile.swift -print-ast | grep ' func ' > result.txt
```